# javascript bitwise and yielding weird results

Tags: javascript, binary, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

In one of my applications in order to simplify logic / heavy db stuff I created a mechanism that relies on the javascript bitwise '&' operator. However this seems to act weird in some occasions.

```
1 & 0 => 0;  11 & 00 => 0;  111 & 000 => 0; 111 & 100 => 100
```

everything ok so far.. but when I try to do this:

```
1100 & 0011 => 8 ;
1100 & 1111 => 1092
```

I get weird results, instead of 0 or 1100. I found out that this happens due to some 'javascript interpretation in a specific base' stuff, however I wonder if there is a solution to this.

Comment: How do you suppose JavaScript should guess that "1100" is 12 in binary and not the number one thousand and one hundred in decimal?

Comment: JavaScript will, like almost any other language, interpret those numbers as **base 10** values.

Answer (score 2):

As per your question you are performing bitwise operation between decimal numbers not binary numbers. In javascript binary number is represented by `prefixing 0b` for eg `2 should be represented as 0b10`.
Another thing is that javascript returns decimal number as a result of bitwise operation. Similarly `hexadecimal number` is represented using `prefex 0x`.

Comment: I don't know how to interpret this. If I type in the js console 0x0 it returns 0, if I type 0x1 or 0x01 it returns 1, fair enough, but if I type 0x10 it returns 16

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake, i have made the correction.

Comment: This is great. Using this combined with the reverse (applying a toString(2) on a number var) one could easily insert bitwise related patterns into js code. Good reply.

Answer (score 1):

When you type `1100` you aren't producing the binary representation of 12, you're writing `1100`. When a number is prefixed with a 0, Javascript interprets that number as being an octal number.

In short, make sure you give the correct decimal numbers to get the proper binary representation.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't act weird.
You're typing decimal numbers which translate to:

```
decimal 1100 = binary 0000010001001100
decimal 0011 = binary 0000000000001011
```

if you `&` them you will get

```
0000000000001000
```

which is 8

the same is with 1100 & 1111